# Why do one post sometimes off-topic post like "How To Boost Marathon Stamina?"

Tags: discussion, scope

Recently I saw a post saying:

> "How To Boost Marathon Stamina?"

Why people do post these type of `off-topic` post on Ask Ubuntu? These are automated robots for posting ads or something else?

Comment: Short answer: yes, these are spammers; such questions should be downvoted and flagged.

Comment: Why negative  vote? Is there any problem asking this question?

Answer (score 4):

This is just spam caused by some very mean bots who like causing us grief in exchange for very shady advertising.

Just flag the posts as spam and move on. They'll get deleted very quickly.

Comment: I'm not so sure they're bots. The spam may very well be posted by real people working for a shady company who pays them a completely unethical salary in exchange for their tireless (and nearly useless) labor.